# Click on EditText won't show the keyboard?

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

I have a table whose tapping on a cell changes its content and displays some edit texts. The first of these edit texts requests the focus, but oddly when I tap on it, the keyboard doesn't show. It is when I tap the others edit texts though. What should I do? Here is how I implemented my first edit text.

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" >
    </requestFocus>
</EditText>
```

When I don't request the focus, there is also a strange behaviour: it opens the keyboard when I tap it but my edit text loses the focus and I've to tap it again to write in it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was because of this line in the Activity block of the Manifest :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"
```

I changed it by :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

Works well now.